# NSIS -- Customize existing button?

Tags: nsis

Thanks for reading this.
I am making a program and I choose to package it using NSIS after getting disappointed by Inno.
I am trying to make a 2 steps install wizard. I could accomplish this by using Nsdialogs and a custom page.
Please see this image: [here](http://preysoft.com/custom.PNG)

Is it possible to change the "Install" button to became "I Agree" as in the license page?
and if this is possible, can this button be colored?

I have searched about this and I found some talk about a plugin called 'Buttonevent'. I download it and I saw the examples. AS I understood this can be used only to Add new buttons Not to change existing ones. 
please help me if there is any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of code for a one-line solution.  **LicenseText** is the attribute you are looking for.  You should also consider using the license page as it is intended, too.
**Page License**

Comment: thank you... the code which Anders gave me work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate
Page InstFiles

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

GetDlgItem $1 $hwndparent 1 ; Get handle to Install/Next button
${NSD_SetText} $1 "$(^AgreeBtn)" 

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Changing button colors is a lot of work and cannot be done in NSIS without a plugin...

Comment: Thank you so much Anders.. I appreciate this a lot. <3